# How to introspect win32com wrapper?

Tags: python, introspection, win32com

I  have a device, which records spectroscopic data and is controlled by a 3rd-party application. For automization purposes, I want to use the COM interface of the application to retrieve the data in Python. Since there is no proper documentation for using the API from Python, I collected the following code from different web sources, which successfully obtains the first frame:

```
comtypes.client.GetModule(('{1A762221-D8BA-11CF-AFC2-508201C10000}', 3, 11))
import comtypes.gen.WINX32Lib as WinSpecLib
win32com.client.pythoncom.CoInitialize()
doc = win32com.client.Dispatch("WinX32.DocFile")

buffer = ctypes.c_float()
frame = 1
spectrum = doc.GetFrame(frame, buffer)
```

However, the call to `GetFrame` is inconsistent with its definition in Visual Basic, which is provided by the manufacturer:

> ```
> Sub GetFrame(frame As Integer, buffer As Variant)
> ```
>
> `GetFrame` copies the data from a document into a Visual Basic array. If `buffer` is an empty Variant, `GetFrame` creates an array of the proper size and data type and sets buffer to point to it before copying the data.

This means that in Visual Basic the variable `buffer` is filled with data while the function `GetFrame` has no return value, whereas in Python `buffer` remains unchanged but the function `GetFrame` does return the actual data.

I wouldn't care about such subtleties, if I hadn't observed random crashes of my program throwing a `MemoryError` and thus indicating a memory leak at this very point of the code. So my suspicion is that for each call to `GetFrame` some memory is allocated for buffer but never released, because `win32com` somehow messed up the API wrapping.

That reasoning leads me to my actual question: How can I introspect that wrapper and understand what it does? So far, I could not find any hints that the code generated by `win32com` is stored in any file, but maybe I just have not been looking at the right places.

In IPython I also tried to get information using `doc.GetFrame??`, but it did not return any implementation:

```
Signature: doc.GetFrame(frame=<PyOleMissing object at 0x06F20BC8>, FrameVariant=<PyOleMissing object at 0x06F20BC8>)
Docstring: <no docstring>
File:      c:\programming\python\src\<comobject winx32.docfile>
Type:      method
```

What else can I try to get more information about the API wrapper?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trying around more, I was finally able to find a solution to my problem. The first important realization was the finding that calling `EnsureDispatch` instead of `Dispatch` gives me access to the wrapper generated by `win32com`.

```
>>> import win32com.client
>>> doc = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch ("WinX32.DocFile")
>>> print(doc.GetFrame.__module__)
'win32com.gen_py.1A762221-D8BA-11CF-AFC2-508201C10000x0x3x12.IDocFile4'
```

In my case the corresponding file was located in the following folder:

```
C:\WinPython\WinPython-32bit-3.5.2.2\python-3.5.2\Lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py\1A762221-D8BA-11CF-AFC2-508201C10000x0x3x12
```

The implementation of `GetFrame` looks as follows.

```
def GetFrame(self, frame=defaultNamedNotOptArg, FrameVariant=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
    'Get Frame Data'
    return self._ApplyTypes_(10, 1, (24, 0), ((2, 1), (16396, 3)), 'GetFrame', None, frame, FrameVariant)
```

So the magic is in method `_ApplyTypes_`. This method itself is defined in `win32com\client\__init__`.

```
def _ApplyTypes_(self, dispid, wFlags, retType, argTypes, user, resultCLSID, *args):
    return self._get_good_object_(
        self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(dispid, 0, wFlags, retType, argTypes, *args),
        user, resultCLSID)
```

We can see that everything is basically passed to `InvokeTypes`. According to [this](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2005-December/004031.html) message on the Python-win32 mailing list, `InvokeTypes` is very similar to `Invoke`, which in turn is a re-implementation of [`IDispatch::Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms887724.aspx). The source code of the C++ implementation integrated in Python can be found [here](https://github.com/Travis-Sun/pywin32/blob/master/com/win32com/src/PyIDispatch.cpp).

Going through this C++ implementation also explains, what bothered me in my original question: The Python version of `Invoke` explicitly turns byref arguments into return values. Hence, at least, there should be no memory leak, which I suspected in the beginning.

Now what can we learn about the argument types? The necessary information is stored in the tuple `((2, 1), (16396, 3))`. We have two arguments, of which the first is an input only argument (indicated by `1`), while the second is an input and output argument (indicated by `3 = 1 | 2`). According to [this](http://joshuaredstone.blogspot.de/2015/02/solidworks-macros-via-python.html) blog entry, the respective first numbers tell us the kind of [`Variant`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/gg251448.aspx) datatype that is expected.

We can look up in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc237865.aspx) list, what the numbers actually mean. The first argument is a signed `int16`, which makes sense, since it specifies the frame number. The second number has the following meaning.

```
16396 = 0x400c = VT_VARIANT | VT_BYREF
```

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc237865.aspx) tells us, what `VT_VARIANT` actually means.

> Either the specified type, or the type of the element or contained field MUST be VARIANT

Not super instructive, but still. It seems that the choice to pass a `ctypes.c_float` is not really a good choice. Instead, I am now passing a variant, as I probably should, inspired by [this](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2012-June/012395.html) discussion.

```
var = win32com.client.VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_VARIANT | pythoncom.VT_NULL | pythoncom.VT_BYREF, None)
spectrum = doc.GetFrame(frame, var)
```

Since making this change, I have no longer observed crashes of this code part, so the original question is solved for me.