# win32com VARIANT: SAFEARRAYS must be sequence

Tags: python, win32com, solidworksapi

I am trying to access data of Solidworks CAD models using it's VBA API from Python via win23com.
I successfully can opened the application and access some data from the file.

Now, I want to port the access to configuration-specific Parameters:
VB code is:

```
    Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
    Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
    Dim swConfigMgr As SldWorks.ConfigurationManager
    Dim vConfName As Variant
    Dim vConfParam As Variant
    Dim vConfValue As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim bRet As Boolean
    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
    Set swConfigMgr = swModel.ConfigurationManager
    Debug.Print "File = " + swModel.GetPathName
    vConfName = swModel.GetConfigurationNames
    For i = 0 To UBound(vConfName)
        bRet = swConfigMgr.GetConfigurationParams(vConfName(i), vConfParam, vConfValue)
        Debug.Assert bRet
        Debug.Print "  Configuration = " & vConfName(i)
        If Not IsEmpty(vConfParam) Then
            For j = 0 To UBound(vConfParam)
                Debug.Print "    " & vConfParam(j) & " = " & vConfValue(j)
            Next j
        End If
    Next i    
End Sub
```

(see here for more details: https://help.solidworks.com/2021/english/api/sldworksapi/Extract_Configuration-Specific_Parameters_Example_VB.htm)

In Python, my code looks like this:

```
...
    configManager = sw.cm
    configurations = doc.GetConfigurationNames

    for config in configurations:
        keys = win32com.client.VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_BYREF | pythoncom.VT_ARRAY, "")
        values = win32com.client.VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_BYREF | pythoncom.VT_ARRAY, "")
        result = configManager.GetConfigurationParams(config, keys, values)
...
```

I am stuck at `GetConfigurationParams` (VB function reference can be found [here](https://help.solidworks.com/2021/english/api/sldworksapi/solidworks.interop.sldworks%7Esolidworks.interop.sldworks.iconfigurationmanager%7Egetconfigurationparams.html))

The Type Library for GetConfigurationParams looks as like this:

```
def GetConfigurationParams(self, ConfigName=defaultNamedNotOptArg, Params=pythoncom.Missing, Values=pythoncom.Missing):
        'Get the parameters for a configuration'
        return self._ApplyTypes_(2, 1, (11, 0), ((8, 1), (16396, 2), (16396, 2)), 'GetConfigurationParams', None,ConfigName
            , Params, Values)
```

From my understanding, I should call `keys,values = configManager.GetConfigurationParams(config)`
but I get `pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352561, 'Parameter nicht optional.', None, None)`

Comment: I'd try keys = win32com.client.VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_BYREF | pythoncom.VT_ARRAY, [])

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tried, but doesn't work. Gives another error `MemoryError: CreatingSafeArray` - question was updated with the information.

Comment: You could try `keys,values = configManager.GetConfigurationParams(config)`. Python doesn't really do reference parameters, instead `win32com` sets the [out] parameters in a returned tuple. Without seeing the Type Library for the object, it's hard to know.

Comment: With `win32com` instead of using `win32com.client.Dispatch()` to create the object, use `win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch()`. This will create Python wrapper files for the object (home/AppData/Local/Temp/gen_py folder). You can look into these Python files which will tell you the signature for each function being called.

Comment: Thanks @DS_London for the suggestions. 

Using `gencache.EnsureDispatch()` also led nowhere at first, as I got `This COM object can not automate the makepy process - please run makepy manually for this object`.

But I figured out how makepy works and ran it on all Solidworks libraries.

I updated the issue description

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

The Type Library had the required information and [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40660996/how-to-introspect-win32com-wrapper) helped understanding what  was written:

```
def GetConfigurationParams(self, ConfigName=defaultNamedNotOptArg, Params=pythoncom.Missing, Values=pythoncom.Missing):
        'Get the parameters for a configuration'
        return self._ApplyTypes_(2, 1, (11, 0), ((8, 1), (16396, 2), (16396, 2)), 'GetConfigurationParams', None,ConfigName
            , Params, Values)
```

The third element of `self._ApplyTypes_` :  `((8, 1), (16396, 2), (16396, 2))` gives hints about the required data:

1. There are 3 function parameters.

```
1: (8, 1)
2: (16396, 2)
3: (16396, 2)
```

2. For each parameter, the first element is the data type:

(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_type_(COM) for reference on VarType, HEX and Propvariant).

Special case: `16396 = 0x400c = VT_BYREF` but VT_BYREF MUST appear in a VARIANT, so its `VT_VARIANT | VT_BYREF`
(Had to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40660996/how-to-introspect-win32com-wrapper) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-oaut/3fe7db9f-5803-4dc4-9d14-5425d3f5461f?redirectedfrom=MSDN) in detail to unterstand)

3. For each parameter, the second element indicates its use:

```
1: input
2: output 
3: both (3 = 1 | 2)
```

So the working solution is

```
config = win32com.client.VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_BSTR, config)
keys = win32com.client.VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_VARIANT | pythoncom.VT_BYREF, [])
values = win32com.client.VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_VARIANT | pythoncom.VT_BYREF, [])

result = configManager.GetConfigurationParams(config, keys, values)
```

`result` return to True and `keys` & `values` to Tuples with the desired outcome.